# Two complex numbers are related if b=a(a+1). are all real numbers related?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Call two complex numbers $a$ and $b$ **related** if $b=a(a+1)$.

*Are all real numbers **related***?

So initially I was thinking that there were separate *strings* of related numbers. For example, $2,6,42$, etc. would belong to one *string*.

I then realized that this was flawed. For example, yes, $6$ is related to $2$, but it's also related to $-3$.

This is because $b$ is related to at least two numbers. So now it seems plausible that this web could possibly relate all numbers.

My hypothesis is that all non-transcendental real numbers are related.

Can someone nudge me in the right direction about proving it, or disproving by contradiction?

NOTE: Two numbers that are related to another number are also related. Transitive property. ThankSS

Comment: What real number is $0$ related to? Also, no integer is related to $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @Dan 0 is related to 0

Comment: I think @Saketh means the former: "this web could possible relate all numbers".

Comment: $-1$ is related to $0$.  But the question isn't clear.  Given $b$ there are at most $2$ values for $a$ which are related to $b$ the way you require.  So are you speaking of a chain of relations?  Or, what exactly?

Comment: What do you mean are all real numbers related?  Obviously $b = 5$ and $a= 32$ we don't have $b = a(a+1)$ so clearly $a$ is not related to $b$.  ANd if $a$ and $b$ are related $b = a(a+1)$ but that $a\ne b(b+1)$ so $b$ and $a$ are not related.  It isn't clear to me what you mean.  Are you saying, perhaps, that $a$ and $b$ are related if either $a=b(b+1)$ or $b=a(a+1)$ and given two $a$ and $b$ there is always a $c$ related to both $a$ and $b$.

Comment: This is not an equivalence relation, as it is not transitive or symmetric. It's not even reflexive for $a\neq0$.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As you can see from the comments, nobody can sort out what you are asking.

Comment: Or are you asking if all numbers $a$ have another number $b$ so that $a$ and $b$ are related (which should be obvious).

Comment: Your relation isn't transitive (or symmetric).  So, so there is no "web."  6 is related to 2.  2 is related  to 1. But 6 is not related to 1.

Comment: It seems fairly obvious to me that you intend to say that relatedness is transitive, I.e. your brother's brother is also your brother but I think if this is what you intend you should state it explicitly to avoid confusion.

Comment: @fleablood your first comment only follows if a and b are related *if and only if* they satisfy the condition given. The question I think is whether the word related implies the transitive property which it does in real life

Comment: "your first comment only follows if a and b are related if and only if they satisfy the condition given"  Considering htat this is supposed to be a definition....  It follows.  $5\ne 32(32+1)$ and $32\ne 5(5+1)$ so either $5$ and $32$ are not related or there is more to the definition of "related" than was stated.  Since th OP claimed that was a *definition* I have to conclude 5 is not related to 32 and, no, not all numbers are related.

Comment: @fleablood for me using the word related in the definition implied transitivity was part of the definition. I guess it's just a different take. Any doubt I had was dispelled by the fact the question's trivial without it.

Comment: I have never seen any serious text in mathematics that would assume transitivity is implied in a definition and need not be stated.

Comment: @fleablood everybody also seems to be assuming symmetry, where reflexivity would be an equally valid assumption given the wording. But since reflexivity gives the trivial solution $a=0$ that meaning can also be quickly ruled out.

Comment: *I* wasn't assuming symmetry.  And I stated so when I wrote " ANd if a and b are related b=a(a+1) but that a≠b(b+1) so b and a are not related".  But it's easy to assume the naivete of the OP assumed symmetric.  That is NOT because symmetry is a reasonable assumption-- it's because symmetry is subtle and it's reasonable to assume the OP didn't know how to distinguish *the language* of comparing a to b from comparing b to a.  But comparing two elements to an infinite chain of other *unstated* elements is *not* a reasonable assumption no matter how much leniency we give to the OP's naivete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume you mean to study the smallest equivalence relation that extends that relation you gave (in other words solving for $a$ or computing $b$ zero or more times in any order).

**Showing that all non-transcendental (algebraic reals) are not related.**

In that case consider the union $F$ of the subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ that can be obtained by successive quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.

No element of $F$ can be related to elements outside of $F$. In fact, if $a\in F$, then $b=a(a+1)\in F$. Also, if $b\in F$, then $a$ is in a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}(b)$, which in turn is a tower of quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore $a\in F$.

There are algebraic real numbers that are not elements of $F$, like $\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Comment: Nice. Although is this perhaps lacking a proof that $F$ is a **proper** subset of $\mathbb{R}$ else it assumes it's conclusion?

Comment: @RobertFrost $F$ is **not** a subset of $R$ (for example $\sqrt{-1}\in F$). It only intersects it (clearly $\sqrt{2}\in F\cap\mathbb{R}$). The argument that $\mathbb{R}\not\subset F$ is the last line.

Comment: I accept your comment is true but it doesn't contradict mine.

Comment: @RobertFrost $F$ cannot be a proper subset if it is not even a subset.

Comment: OK but the point still stands that you fail to show their intersection is a proper subset of R

Comment: @RobertFrost Meh! Showing that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=3$ is for kids. You do it as an exercise.

Comment: I couldn't but I think completing your answer would make a great answer even better.

Comment: @RobertFrost Do it. Anyone can edit an answer.

Comment: I already said I can't. It's not a contest.

Comment: @RobertFrost Start by writing the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt[3]{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, which is $x^3-2$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$. Now use long division to find a basis of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: You are seriously overestimating my capabilities! It's known as the reverse Dunning Kruger effect. But I may just try that as an exercise in the morning.

Comment: @RobertFrost Try to google "degree of algebraic number". Seriously, this is some basic number theory; should it be included in an answer? Or should we better always start from 1+1=2?

Comment: @yo.  That tag was "algebra-precalculus".  "basic number theory" most certainly should *not* be assumed. On the other hand, an answer need not actually show anything but just explain how to figure it out.  On the third hand I would not expect th OP to have the slightest idea what a "subfield" or what a quadratic extension was or what F was supposed to be. Nor why $\sqrt[3]2$ is not in F.  I have to agree with Robert Frost on this comment.

Comment: i apologize, i kind of just guessed on the tag because i had no clue what algebraic number theory or field things are @fleablood

Answer (score 1):

If $a $ and $b $ are real, then

$$a^2+a-b=0$$
with $$1+4b\ge 0$$

thus we need $$b\ge \frac {-1}{4} $$

For example, if $b=-1$, there is no real $a $ such that
$$a(a+1)=-1$$

Comment: But $-1\leq\frac{-1}{4}$

Comment: @RobertFrost No real $a $ is related to $-1$.

Comment: $0$ is related to $-1$

Comment: "0 is related to -1".  No, it isn't.  $-1 \ne 0(0+1)$.  Salahamam Fatima has shown that nothing is related to anything less than $-\frac 14$.   But even more simply  $1 \ne 2*(2+1)$ so $1$ is not related to $2$ and it only takes only one counter example to prove not all numbers are related.

Answer (score 0):

"Are all real numbers related?"

Well, is it true that for all $a$ and $b$ that $b = a(a+1)$ always?

That seems a little hard to believe.  I picked to numbers at random $a=2$ and $b = 6$ and found that $6 = 2(2+1)$.  Then I picked two more at random $a = 11$ and $b= 132$ and $132 = 11(11+1)$.  And then I picked two more at random $a = \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2$ and $b = 5 + 2\sqrt{6} + \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2$ and got $(\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2)(\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2 + 1) = 3 + \sqrt 6 + \sqrt 6 + 2 + \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2 = 5 + 2\sqrt{6} + \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2$

So it seemed that that was true.  At least for the ones I guessed at random.

But we can't just guess at random and declare true an a basis of a few samples.  We must prove it is always true.

$b = a(a+1)$ if and only if $b = a^2 + a$ if and only if $a^2 + a +b = 0$.  By this quadratic formula that is true when $a = \frac {-1\pm\sqrt{1-4b}}2$.

So is it true that any two numbers picked is will always be true that $a = \frac {-1\pm\sqrt{1-4b}}2$.

Is that true that for any two number that will always be true.  If $b = 0$ then $a = -1$ or $a=0$.   Is it true that *every* number is equal to either $0$ or $1$.

It took me a lot of thinking but I finally came up with an example of a number that was not equal to $-1$ or $0$.  $1$ is not $-1$ nor $0$.  There might be others but $1$ is an example of a number that is neither $-1$ nor $0$.

So $b=0$ and $a=1$ we get $b = 0 \ne 2 = 1(1+1) = a(a+1)$.

So $0$ and $1$ are not related because $0 \ne 1(1+1)$.

So not all numbers are related.

That might be the only counter-example. (It was the only one I could come up with)  But we only need one counter example.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the relation
\begin{equation}
b=a(a+1),
\end{equation}
define a string to be a sequence of numbers such that each is related to the ones before and after it, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
a_{n+1}=a_n(a_n+1).
\end{equation}
This can be viewed as a dynamical system, with $n$ playing the role of time.  Note that if $T:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is the time evolution operator given by
\begin{equation}
T(x)=x(x+1),
\end{equation}
then the inverse time evolution operator on (the powerset of) $\mathbb{C}$, $T^{-1}:\mathbb{P(C)}\to\mathbb{P(C)}$, is given by
\begin{equation}
T^{-1}(\{x\})=\begin{cases}\left\{\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2},\frac{-1-\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}\right\}&\text{, if } x\neq-\frac{1}{4}\\\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\right\}&\text{, if }x=-\frac{1}{4}\end{cases}.
\end{equation}
So, given a value in a string, all "future" values are determined, while in general "past" values need not be uniquely determined.

I interpret the OP's question to be: fix $r,s\in\mathbb{R}$, does there exist a sequence of $T$'s and $T^{-1}$'s such that
\begin{equation}
r\in T^{m_N}(T^{-m_{N-1}}(T^{m_{N-2}}(\cdots{}T^{m_1}(T^{-m_0}(s))\cdots{}))),
\end{equation}
where $T$ here is the set function induced by $T(x)$ as defined above.
Since
\begin{equation}
TT^{-1}=\mathbb{I},
\end{equation}
this reduces to: do there exist $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{equation}
r\in T^{-m}(T^{n}(s))\Leftrightarrow T^m(r)=T^n(s)\Leftrightarrow \cup_{p=0}^nT^{-p}(T^p(s))\cap\cup_{q=0}^mT^{-q}(T^q(r))\neq\emptyset.
\end{equation}
Counterexample to OP's conjecture that all algebraic numbers are related: 1 and 3 are not related.  Suppose 1 and 3 were related, then there are smallest non-negative integers $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$  such that $T^m(1)=T^n(3)$.  $T(1)=2\neq3$, $T(2)=6\neq3$, since $T(x)$ is an increasing function of $x$, $m$ and $n$ must both be positive.  Consider $T^{m-1}(1)$ and $T^{n-1}(3)$.  These must both have positive values, since they are iterations of $T$ applied to positive numbers.  They must also be elements of $T^{-1}(\{T^m(1)\})=T^{-1}(\{T^n(3)\})$.  This contradicts the fact that for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x>0$, $T^{-1}(\{x\})$ has exactly one positive element and one negative element.

Conclusion: if one has a string containing 1 and a string containing 3, then these strings do not share any elements.  I imagine that this relation (numbers being equivalent if there are strings containing them that share elements), far from relating all algebraic numbers, partitions the integers into countably many equivalence classes.